# Append html to button's closest div with specified class with javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the next HTML structure:

```
<div class='form-row'>
    <div class='col-2'>
        Blah Blah
    </div>
    <div class='col-4'>
        <button type='button' class='add_row'>+</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

On `add_row` button click, I need to add another `form-row` div next to closest to button `form-row` div, so the result will be like:

```
<div class='form-row'>
    <div class='col-2'>
        Blah Blah
    </div>
    <div class='col-4'>
        <button type='button' class='add_row'>+</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='form-row'>
    <div class='col-2'>
        Blah Blah
    </div>
    <div class='col-4'>
        <button type='button' class='add_row'>+</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to use jQuery script:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_row', function () {

    $(this).closest('.form-row').append("<div class='form-row'>div contents</div>");

 });
```

But it appends it AFTER the direct parent of the button (`<div class='col-4'>`).

What is the correct jquery to append to a closest div with specified class instead?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter

Comment: You're not wanting to append **to** the element, but **after** it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wanting to add a sibling to the form-row, not content.  To do that you can use either `insertAfter()` or `after()`.

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '.add_row', function (e) {
  $(e.target).closest('.form-row').after('<div class="form-row">Content</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form-row'>
  <div class='col-2'>
    Blah Blah
  </div>
  <div class='col-4'>
    <button type='button' class='add_row'>+</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='form-row'>
  <div class='col-2'>
    Blah Blah
  </div>
  <div class='col-4'>
    <button type='button' class='add_row'>+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Swapping the `append` with `after` did the trick, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

edit: use `$(el).after()` like @Taplar suggested. Updated code below

---

When you do `$(el).append(...)`, you are appending into `$(el)`.
What you want is to append to the parent of `$(el)`, aka `$(el).parent()`.

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.add_row', function () {

  $(this).closest('.form-row').after("<div class='form-row'>div contents</div>");
 });
});
```

Note that if you want to copy the `.form-row`, you'd need to clone it before appending it.

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.add_row', function () {
    const $formRow = $(this).closest('.form-row');
    $formRow.parent().after($formRow.clone());
  });
});
```

---

Vanilla Javascript, for reference:

```
const $formRow = document.querySelector('.form-row');

document.onclick = (e) => {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('add_row')) return;
  $container.after($formRow.cloneNode(true));
};
```

Comment: @Taplar ah you're right, I missed that, thanks! I've update my answer, since it might still be useful for op or other.

Answer (score 0):

little change in your code

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_row', function (e) {
  $(this).closest('.form-row').clone().insertAfter($(this).closest('.form-row'));
});
```